# Schema Theorem in genetic algorithm simulation framework

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I've been studying Genetic Algorithm for a while and now I'd like to move forward and check on assumptions made in my designs. I've been working with Frameworks, besides my own implementations as DEAP, PyEvolve, etc. being a python lover.

Now, I'd like to find a framework where I could study Schema Theorem results from GA, do you know of a framework where I could get simulation results or similar? Schemes associated to started population and later evolution of them, building blocks, analysis of Variation Operators, etc.

I'd rather prefer something in Python, but any language would be OK, even any webpage with live running results or results from previous experiments.

I'd also interested in Dynamical Systems approach and Markov Chain Analysis.